# StumbleUpon - automatic refresh or trigger of 'Stumble' button

Tags: javascript, html, triggers

We have TV's in our office, which show videos and other various real-time data.

What I'd like to be able to do is put the browser on one of the TV's to something like http://www.stumbledupon.com/random and what it does is every 30 seconds, triggers the "Stumble" button and reload to a new random website in our range of interests.

This would be a great way for us to showcase websites on an unmanned machine.

Is there anyway to do this with the current website ?

Comment: how are you showing videos and other real-time data? Server from a website or connected to cable etc?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
setTimeout(doreload, 30000);

function doreload() {
  location.reload(true);
}
```

On this same page have an iframe with the current random site.

On page load on the server end set the iframe source to a random site.

Edit:

Optionally you can handle it all on the javascript side.

Comment: You shouldn't pass strings to `setTimeout`, it uses `eval`.  Pass a function instead.